# How to get custom task tags to work in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

tried this many times but I just can't figure out how to define custom tags in Tasks. I used the dialog and created different things like "TODO2" , or "V2" or "TOVO" (just for testing)... but none of these will ever scan into tasks, even though I do things like //TODO2 or //V2 or //TOVO in source code.

I also tried restarting eclipse but that didn't help?

anyone have any ideas how to use this functionality properly?

I want to make a tag I can use for future version TODOs... like for V2 of my program.

Right now I'm just hacking it like this //TODO FUTURE blah ... so that I can quickly see that I should ignore reading this task for now (since I'm only on v1 development)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What dialog did you use to add task tags ? You should go in "Windows -> Preferences", and next "Java -> Compiler -> Task tags". In this dialog you can add task tags. Make sure that your project is using the global task tags (otherwise you must add task tags specific to your project in the project properties dialog).

When you close the preference dialog, Eclipse should recompile your project, and the task view will show the new tags.

Comment: ah! I didn't see the one for java tags... that was it... global task tags only work in non-java files like XML... so I must create my new tags in 2 different places... Global dialog and Java tasks dialog... thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

add new task tags for java:  Windows -> Preferences

[image]

[image]