# Possible to specify Eclipse task tag colors by priority?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is specifically for the `Eclipse IDE`. I know it is possible to edit the `color` (and `font`, etc.) of task tags by going to:

```
Preferences->Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring->Comments->Task Tags
```

But what I'd like to do is define different colors for different task tag priorities. For example, `TODO` is Normal priority, and so should be blue in color; while `FIXME` is High priority, and so should be red in color.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Edit: This is in the Java editor itself.

Comment: Do you want to these tags in colour in java editor or in **Task** or **Markers** view?

Comment: In the Java editor. I generally don't use the Task or Markers views. I've edited the question to specify that.

Comment: I have seen that the task tags you are looking for (i.e. TODO, FIXME). It is possible in `Preferences->Java->Compiler->Task Tags`.
I am using eclipse Juno and its available there.
Please refer to link might that help you. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296338/how-to-get-custom-task-tags-to-work-in-eclipse)

Comment: @MandarPandit: The dialog that you recommended will not allow me to set the COLORS of those tags at all. Just the tag name and priority.

Answer (score 3):

It is not yet possible - the configuration (under `General → Editors → Text Editors → Annotations` only allows to set one color for task tags. It would be possible to extend the Annotations code to allow to differentiate Task tags by priority, but so far no one has done that.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439883 (Provide separate annotation specs for low/normal/high tasks)

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456635 (Separate styles for different task priorities)